# Group and merge JSON properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grouping

I have a JSON object which has repeating email property as follows:

```
accounts": [
{
  "email": "somebody@domain.com",
  "accountID": 1,
  "accountName": "Account Name",
  "permission": "Permission 1",
  "nodeID": 1
},
{
  "email": "somebody@domain.com",
  "accountID": 1,
  "accountName": "Account Name",
  "permission": "Permission 2",
  "nodeID": 2
}]
```

That JSON contains repeating email fields which I want to group by. The desired resulting JSON is as follows:

```
{
  “email” : ”somebody@domain.com”, 
  “accountID” : 1,
  “accountName” : “Account Name”,
  “permissions” : [
    { 
        “permission” : “Permission 1”,
        “nodeID” : 1
    },
    { 
        “permission” : “Permission 2”,
        “nodeID” : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

So, in this way the resulting JSON won't contain more than 1 item with the same email property.

Is there any way this can be achieved with jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? I think `.extend()` might be what you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: This is about manipulating data in JavaScript; "with jQuery" is unnecessary.

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to merge 2 objects, but rather group by a property and merge the other properties.

Comment: @Jacob the way I understood it, the code is already using jQuery so the idea is to achieve the goal with it (as opposed to finding a 'pure JS' way of doing it and then integrate it with jquery)

Comment: Look at Underscore's `groupBy()` method: http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy. It doesn't do exactly what you want to achieve, but it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily with a `forEach` loop:

```js
var source = {accounts: [
{
  "email": "somebody@domain.com",
  "accountID": 1,
  "accountName": "Account Name",
  "permission": "Permission 1",
  "nodeID": 1
},
{
  "email": "somebody@domain.com",
  "accountID": 1,
  "accountName": "Account Name",
  "permission": "Permission 2",
  "nodeID": 2
}]};

var groups = {};

source.accounts.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(item.email)) {
        groups[item.email] = {
            email : item.email,
            accountID : item.accountID,
            accountName: item.accountName,
            permissions: []
        };
    }
    groups[item.email].permissions.push({
        permission: item.permission,
        nodeID: item.nodeID
    });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(groups));
```

We create an empty object and then we loop through your original array. For each item in the array we check if we have this email already and, if not, we insert it into the object along with the `accountID` and `accountName` and we create an empty array for permissions. Then we just add the permissions to the array.

You'll end up with an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "somebody@domain.com": {
        "email": "somebody@domain.com",
        "accountID": 1,
        "accountName": "Account Name",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "permission": "Permission 1",
                "nodeID": 1
            },
            {
                "permission": "Permission 2",
                "nodeID": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With a key for each e-mail address. You can loop through that with a `for...in` loop if you need to.